# How to see the given array NAME using the magic method __set

Tags: php, class, oop, methods, set

If there is an unexpected array definition in my instance, how do I access the given array NAME using the magic method __set?

For example I want to echo out the array name that was submitted:

```
class App {

__set(){

// echo array name

}

$app = new App();
$app->arrayName->['key'=>'val'];
```

How to echo out arrayName or set a new name for the submitted array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__set()` takes two parameters, the name and value, see [PHP : Property Overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set):

```
public function __set($name, $value){
    if(is_array($value)) { echo "$name is an array"; }
}
```

Then set the array with:

```
$app = new App();
$app->arrayName = ['key'=>'val'];
```

Then `__set()` would display `arrayName is an array`.